# IBM Watson Assistant: How can you determine if telephony is being used in Watson Assistant Actions?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Using the new actions I want to be able to easily filter if the user is on the phone or the web, to give different responses. It doesn't have an option to set this.

Comment: @data_henrik Not sure what your edit adds to the question.

Comment: I added the `ibm-cloud` tag and put the IBM Watson Assistant to the front of the question. Both to improve the context

Comment: I added also `ibm-watson` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following [attribute](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-responses-json#dialog-responses-json-target-integrations.) via editing the JSON response to have different responses per channel.

In addition there are [context variables](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-integrations) that you can condition upon.

Comment: Thanks. While mine works your second link is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [V1 logging](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v1?code=python#listlogs) mechanism you can pull the user logs and compare differences across user channels.

In the context object when telephony is being used, there is a number of variables that are needed in that channel. Checking for one of those variables will allow you to filter.

For the new actions phone channel feature the following conditional will return true if it is being used.

```
context?.has("vgwSIPFromURI")
```